# How to use Max3795 for driving VCSEL at 100 MHz?

Tags: driver, optoelectronics, mosfet-driver, laser-diode, laser-driver

i am trying to drive my OPV380 see datasheet( http://optekinc.com/datasheets/OPV380.pdf) with a square wave data at 100 MHz. i am using now a Max3795 (http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX3795.pdf) as a driver.

i used the same circuit as the datasheet but i replaced the ferrit bead inductor with a resistor of 2 Mega Ohm, and TX_disable is connected to ground. The problem is that i don't get any output at the cathode of the VCSEL.

does anyone has an experience with this driver that can help to solve the problem?
or is there is any simple current mirror circuit that can do the Job ?

Answer (score 1):

As Peter B. said, it's hard to get a lot of current through a 2 Meg resistor :^)

I don't know the IC or laser.  But I've used a [bias Tee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_tee) with ~ 50 ohm resistor in the RF line to modulate a laser at 100's of MHz.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that part at all, but I will say that a ferrite bead has a DC resistance of approximately zero.  Since the bead is in series with the laser, replacing it with a 2 Megohm resistor is definitely going to make the laser extremely dim, if it lights at all.

If you can't get a suitable ferrite bead, you might try a very low value resistor in its place - 5 ohms or so might work.